# Apple-app-site-association not found

Tags: ios9, corespotlight, ios-universal-links

I'm trying to pass the [Apple Search Validation Tool](https://search.developer.apple.com/appsearch-validation-tool/), and I'm having problems with the apple-app-site-association.

For some reason the bot can't find my file. But if you open the URL it's there.

It's not a formatting problem, because the file isn't even found. 
I have https so it's not needed to sign my file.

I don't have any extension on my file, as asked in the documentation.

Someone had a similar problem and asked on the [Apple Developer foruns](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/81973#81973), but it didn't help me.

My url is https://ps3looke.ottvs.com.br/apple-app-site-association

I tried to check it with cUrl and everything seems normal:

```
Caios-MacBook-Air:~ caiocoan$ curl -I https://ps3looke.ottvs.com.br/apple-app-site-association
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 135
Content-Type: application/json
Last-Modified: Tue, 27 Oct 2015 15:36:52 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "f81e714dcd10d11:0"
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 04 Nov 2015 20:43:25 GMT
```

Any ideia of what I could be doing wrong, or what I need to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am currently contacting Microsoft Support over the same issue. My initial accessment is that Windows Server 2012 R2 has a bug in handling TLS 1.2, which is the HTTPS protocol that AppleBot uses crawl the pages.

Your apple-app-site-association looks perfectly fine

**Edit**

I found that even with the validation tool not working, when you visit the site on Safari on the iPad/iPhone, the Open in the xxx app does pop out

**Update 2015-12-22**

Microsoft has gotten back to me. The issue is that AppleBot sends the following Client Hello to initiate SSL connection

```
Signature Hash Algorithms (4 algorithms)
    Signature Hash Algorithm: 0x0401
        Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA256 (4)
        Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: RSA (1)
    Signature Hash Algorithm: 0x0403
        Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA256 (4)
        Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: ECDSA (3)
    Signature Hash Algorithm: 0x0201
        Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA1 (2)
        Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: RSA (1)
    Signature Hash Algorithm: 0x0203
        Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA1 (2)
        Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: ECDSA (3)
```

When you look at the certificate hierarchy of your SSL certificate, you see

```
COMODO RSA Organization Validation Secure Server CA
    Certificate signature algorithm
        PKCS #1 SHA-384 With RSA Encryption
```

When Windows Server receives the Client Hello from AppleBot, it sees that AppleBot supports SHA1 and SHA256, however, your certificate requires support for SHA384. Thus, according to https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.4.1.4.1, there is no way to fulfil the request and Windows Server resets the connection. AppleBot then reports as file not found.

Specifically, RFC5246 says

```
   If the client provided a "signature_algorithms" extension, then all
   certificates provided by the server MUST be signed by a
   hash/signature algorithm pair that appears in that extension.
```

*Remedy suggested by Microsoft*

When you need to use the validator, create a self-signed certificate. By default, Windows uses SHA1 as the certificate signature algorithm. Bind the self-signed cert to your HTTPS endpoint, then use the validator to ensure that your apple-app-site-association file is okay. You can then switch back to the actual SSL certificate you bought.

*My warning*

Do not put a self-signed cert on your production server. Create another server to test!

Comment: I see. Thanks for your answer, if you have any news could you edit and share it?

Comment: @KioCoan MS Support found the problem

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this issue with URL Rewrite module by adding a .json extension to the filename and then adding a rewrite rule to my web.config as follows:

```
<rule name="AppleAppSite" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^apple-app-site-association$"/>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="apple-app-site-association.json"/>
</rule>
```